# Use regex to parse id from string that has been generated using xeger java library

Tags: java, regex

I was thinking about hiding my ids while sending. For this I made use of xeger java library to generate strings based on ids and send it. On the receiving end I need to parse this to get the value of id. So I need to make use of the regular expression that I use to generate the string and grab the id in the receiver side.

This is my java code to generate string according to the regular expression. I am using xeger for generating string. x is the value of id which can be any integer value.

```
int x = 2;
String regex = "(a|b)(1|1000)[cd]{3}["+x+"](a|b)[cd]{3}";
Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
String result = generator.generate();
System.out.println("Generated String is : " + result);
```

Below are some outputs that this program generates during different runs :

```
b1000dcc2bcdc
b1000dcc2bddc
a1000dcd2acdc
```

I just want to get the x value from the generated string using the regular expression. I tried to use the regular expression :
`(a|b)(1|1000)[cd]{3}(.)(a|b)[cd]{3}` to get the value of x from the generated strings but it doesnot give me the value of x.
I used the https://regex101.com/ online regex tester and the regular expression that I have used to get the value of x in the string b1000dcc2bcdc gives me four matches : b, 1000, 2 , b. I only need the value of x which is 2.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem in taking the 3rd value from the matching array?. Your regex is meant to parse the value group by group

Comment: Is your `x` always a single character?

Comment: @PM77-1 No, it can be any integer value from 0 to 100,000

Comment: Then you need to adjust your expression since it's currently looking for a single character.

Comment: @PM77-1 I have adjusted the regular expression. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Java, but the thing here is that every pair of parenthesis creates a "matching group", that is why you get a result for each parenthesized expression.

You can tell the regex engine to NOT capture whatever substring matches the expression inside a particular pair of parenthesis by adding "?:" before the expression, this is, replace

```
(a|b)(1|1000)[cd]{3}(.)(a|b)[cd]{3}
```

with

```
(?:a|b)(?:1|1000)[cd]{3}(.)(?:a|b)[cd]{3}
```

You could also replace "(a|b)" with "[ab]", which is the same from a semantic point of view:

```
[ab](?:1|1000)[cd]{3}(.)[ab][cd]{3}
```

And while we are at it, given that your options for the second group are "1" and "1000", you can make the 1 mandatory and a group of three zeroes optional:

```
[ab]1(?:000)?[cd]{3}(.)[ab][cd]{3}
```

But that might just be for the sake of it :)

The real solution is to count your parenthesis and ask the code to give you the correct group inside the match, the library you are using should have something like "result.getGroup(3)" or similar.